# Camel-cxf stop route shutdown the bus

Tags: java, apache-camel, camel-cxf

I have an error that I can not fix with camel. When I stop and delete a camel route that uses cxf. I get the following log:

```
 INFO  o.a.c.s.SpringCamelContext - Route: TOTO-S is stopped, was 
consuming from: direct://secondMouvement-TOTO
16:37:13.728 [http-nio-18203-exec-3] INFO  o.a.c.s.SpringCamelContext - 
Route: TOTO-S is shutdown and removed, was consuming from: 
direct://secondMouvement-TOTO
16:37:13.729 [http-nio-18203-exec-3] INFO  o.a.c.c.c.CxfEndpoint - shutdown 
the bus ... org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBus@48f47737
```

The problem is that I have cxf services exposed by my webapp as well as other routes. And I have no more service exposed by my webapp after this stop ...

I am currently in camel 2.22 and cxf 3.2.5

My route TOTO just does this at the end :

```
<to uri="cxf://{{TOTO-S.wss.url}}?serviceName={{{TOTO-S.wss.namespace}}}{{TOTO-S.wss.servicename}}&amp;portName={{{TOTO-S.wss.namespace}}}{{TOTO-S.wss.portname}}&amp;dataFormat=PAYLOAD" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I try to revive the subject, nobody has an idea?
I specify that ideally I should not touch the "to uri", I must find a way during the removal of the road not to stop the bus Spring